# How to prove a Series + log function is a constant on an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let the following series be equal to A(X);

A(X) = $\sum_{n=1}^∞ x^n/n $

We know A(X) has a Radius of convergence = 1.

How can I prove A(X) + log(1-x) in constant on the interval (-1,1)?

I know this constant is 0 by finding the expansion of both and summing them, but how can I prove that it's constant (without having to find that it's 0)? Thank you.

Comment: Try to prove that the derivative equals 0, i.e. $$  \frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dx} (A(x) + \log(1-x) ) = 0. $$

Comment: What would this mean and how would I go about doing this after differentiating?

Comment: Some typesetting problem here. I assume you meant $A (x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n$. Inside the disc of convergence, the power series could be **differentiated term by term**.

Comment: Yes I did sorry. I understand you could do that, but how does that prove it's always the same constant.

Comment: If the derivative of some function that defined on an interval is 0, then itself is a constant function.

Comment: Oh yes of course! Thank you a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!